# CoreLocation - Continuous location update in background with authorizedWhenInUse authorization

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I need to track the user location in background, like the navigation feature in waze and apple maps.

However, I want to use it with **authorizedWhenInUse**  permission.

As I understand, application can keep track of user location even with **authorizedWhenInUse** permission, as in this state, application considered **foreground** (Blue line appears on top of the status bar - means that the user knows that the application doing location work)

It all works fine when I grant **authorizedAlways** permission.

However, when the permission is **authorizedWhenInUse**, and I send the application to background, the blue line appears, but application gets terminated after about one minute, and the following message appears in the log:
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Here is how I track location updates before going to background:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

And my plist contains the background mode:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with Core Location. Signal 9 indicates you’ve been killed for using too much memory or similar. You probably need to release resources before going into the background. Or you may be trying to do other things in the background that you have not told us about.

Comment: "It all works fine If the user grant authorizedAlways permission."

Comment: you know that Signal 9 doesn't always means memory issue. It can be received in some other cases.
However it good idea to check using your resources. Active UI updates can cause terminate app. Using Instruments - it's good idea.
Also, check if you set filter for your location updates and don't process each location update. @dor506

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "or similar" and "you may be trying to do other things".

Comment: This was indeed the case. I noticed that after sending the app to background, the cpu usage increases to 120% (!!), due to a bug in some view animation. As for now (after fixing the issue and the cpu is in 0%), the app 'survives' in the background with authorizedWhenInUse authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `showsBackgroundLocationIndicator` property to true

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_location_services_authorization_to_request says:

> Location services are available to apps with
>   CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse only while the app is “in
>   use”. On all platforms that support When In Use authorization, an app
>   is considered in use:
>
> - When the app runs in the foreground.
> - In the few seconds after an app leaves the foreground, a short grace
>     period for your app to finish any current location tasks the user
>     initiated.
> - When the app shows the background location usage indicator
>     (showsBackgroundLocationIndicator). On iOS, the indicator is a blue
>     bar or pill at the top of the screen; on watchOS it’s a small icon.

It would be nice to read the whole article :)

If you don't want to see blue bar at top, use `authorizedAlways` auth type.

Comment: It’s about the crash, not the blue bar.